# Bootstrap, why does position:fixed shift the content & make the row not found?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I always think I understand CSS positioning, but then get frustrated again. Ok when I have `position:static`, i.e., default, my page looks like this (shown with inspect element highlighting the parent `row` of the `col-xs-*` that contains the date picker content):

[image]

I would like to keep everything about that page the exact same EXCEPT that I want to fix the `col-xs-*` that contains the date picker content, so that when the page scrolls down (not in the Fiddle example), it would float on top. Nevermind the `z-index`, I just noticed, that the minute I apply `position:fixed`, something interesting happens. Here's a screenshot again where I inspect element and tried to highlight parent `row` of the `col-xs-*` that is fixed. Notice 2 things: 1) The parent `row` isn't highlighted in blue on the page; no idea where it went, 2) The content has shifted right for some reason. It's no longer centered above "Comparison's sake" text.

[image]

Can someone please explain this behavior to me? I think it's persistently messing up my code. My end goal is again to keep everything centered as in the first snapshot, but just fix the `col-xs-*`.

Code in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2v3gpa7x/

The relevant `col-xs-*` has id `date-row`

Comment: Once you use `position: fixed` you remove element from flow and bootstrap positioning doesn't apply anymore so you have to center it like this https://jsfiddle.net/2v3gpa7x/1/

Comment: what does this `transform: translateX(-50%);` do?

Comment: It moves element on x axis, so in this case it will move element left for `50%` of its own width.

Comment: Ah ok, so why do I need to have left: 50% and that? Just trying to learn, this worked

Answer (score 0):

For any type of scrolling to work you need to use 
{position:*absolute*;top:0;left:0;margin:0 auto;} The term 'auto' keeps the page content centered horizontally. "absolute" allows it all to move as a group.
 If I understood more of what you wanted I could add ul 'wrappers' to force the position of any object